# AWS api trying to call iself gets StatusCodeError: 307 Temporary redirect using node request-promise

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, request-promise

I have an Aws Api gateway which calls itself recusrively (triggers a post to the API with a new package body) . However when it tries to make a call to itself it gets a StatusCodeError: 307 Temporary redirect.

The request is made with the request-promise package and the culprit function is below:

```
    async function callSelf(json)
{

    console.log("Calling self")

    options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: url,
        body:JSON.stringify(json)

    };

   await rp(options).then( function (err,resp){console.log(err);console.log(resp)})
    console.log("Called itself")
}
```

Please help this has been driving me crazy for days.

The error thrown by console.log(err) is:

```
4a5420a4-73cc-11e8-8d5f-c7ef7ef87853    StatusCodeError: 307 - "<html>\r\n<head><title>307 Temporary Redirect
</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>307 Temporary Redirect</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>CloudFront</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
at new StatusCodeError (/var/task/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:32:15)
at Request.plumbing.callback (/var/task/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:104:33)
at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/var/task/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
at Request.self.callback (/var/task/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/request/request.js:1157:10)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/request/request.js:1079:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

edit: added error log

Comment: Where exactly is this http status being output? Gateway logs? if so was it for the initial or recursive call? Lambda logs? If the 307 response is to the client calling the API, can you see a Location header in the response?

Comment: The http is being output by the rp promise console.log(err). The first call works only when it calls itself from within ie I can hit the api from postman. THe full stack trace Ill add above

Comment: Is the api gateway logging the request from the lambda?

Comment: no it doesnt actualy reach it